# How to convert listof list into single list without import

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

My list is:

```
a = [[1,2], [23,51,6], ["Hi", "hello"]]
```

I want ouput:

```
a = [ 1,2,23 51,6, "Hi", "hello"]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
>>> a = [[1,2], [23,51,6], ["Hi", "hello"]]
>>> [x for xs in a for x in xs]
[1, 2, 23, 51, 6, 'Hi', 'hello']
```

Comment: `sum` works, but it incurs needless O(n^2) performance. Even if you expect small input sizes, it should pretty much never be used for this.

Comment: @user2357112, Thank you for comment. I removed the solution that use `sum`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `sum` with two arguments, the list of lists and the empty list to add to:

```
>>> sum(a, [])
[1, 2, 23, 51, 6, 'Hi', 'hello']
```

which is really a special case of `reduce`:

```
>>> reduce(list.__add__, a)
[1, 2, 23, 51, 6, 'Hi', 'hello']
```

In fact, I believe Guido's rationale for removing `reduce` from Python 3's built-ins is that most people just use it for adding lists of things (usually numbers). Once the `sum` function was added, `reduce` became much less important. Python 3 requires an import to use `reduce`.

If you didn't care about importing a module, another option is [`itertools.chain`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) which returns an iterator that iterates over all the elements in all of its parameters. You can use the `list` constructor to turn that iterator into a list:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> list(itertools.chain(*a))
[1, 2, 23, 51, 6, 'Hi', 'hello']
```

Comment: `sum` works, but it incurs needless O(n^2) performance when linear-time solutions are readily available.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [itertools.chain.from_iterable](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) method:

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> a = [[1,2], [23,51,6], ["Hi", "hello"]]
>>> list(chain.from_iterable(a))
[1, 2, 23, 51, 6, 'Hi', 'hello']
```

Note that this will not work with more than 2 levels of nesting.